# Filtering multidimensional array in uitableview - swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array, filter

Here is my model

```swift
class BusinessProfile: NSObject {
    var title: String?
    var website: String?
    var associatedOrganization: String?
    var companyName: String?
    
    var productList: [BusinessProfileProduct]?
}

class BusinessProfileProduct: NSObject{    
    var productName: Double?
    var modelNumber: String?
    var hsCode: String?
}
```

Here are my array variables in view controller.

```
var businessProfileArray = [BusinessProfile]()
var tempBusinessProfileArray = [BusinessProfile]()
```

I already have filtered businessProfileArray on the basis of companyName like below:

```
tempBusinessProfileArray = businessProfileArray.filter({ (BusinessProfile) -> Bool in
            return (BusinessProfile.companyName!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
        })
```

But I am unable to filter businessProfileArray on the basis of productName or hsCode from nested array of BusinessProfileProduct.

Note: businessProfileArray contains array of businessProfileProduct

**Any help from anyone? Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something similar to this

```
func filterArr(searchText:String) -> [BusinessProfile] {
    var filteredArr = [BusinessProfile]()
    for profile in businessProfileArray {
        var isMatched = false
        
        if let matchedProduct = profile.productList.filter ({$0.companyName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}).first {
            isMatched = true
            print(matchedProduct.companyName)
        }
        
        if isMatched {
            filteredArr.append(profile)
        }
        
    }
    
    return filteredArr
}
```

this will return all the profiles in which there is a match of searchText with product's companyName however it will not remove the extra products which does not match the searchText

Comment: @Sptibo happy to help :)

Comment: @Sptibo if it solved your problem please consider an upvote, thank you